# Getting no value from Gravity TDS sensor (analog pin)

Tags: esp32

I'm using this ESP32 model (picture)
with Expressif's DOIT ESP32 Dev 1 library for esp32. And I was trying to use Gravity TDS sensor with DFRobot Gravity library.
I set my Analog pin from A1 (Arduino) to pin 32.
Used this settings

```cpp
gravityTds.setPin(32);
gravityTds.setAref(3.3);
gravityTds.setAdcRange(4096);
```

Connected plus to 3.3 and minus to ground.
But I was getting a `inf` in source code for `Voltage` variable because of zero division so I could not callibrate the sensor. I tried to search for it and found that `AnalogRead(pin, INPUT)` returning 0, or 0.00 if float.

Im not sure why. I tried to get a value by myself from a simple AnalogRead code, but it was same. I have the Analog cable connected to D32 pin. Am I doing something wrong?
Is 32 not good pin? I tried same pin with Analog Temp read by Gravity also. I was getting a value normaly[image]

Comment: Are you able to find a multimeter/voltmeter to read the voltage and see if it is actually 3.3 ? Maybe the input is left "floating" and the gravity library cant read it ! (Pun intended)

Comment: I connected multimeter to + and - of the sensor and i shows 3.34. When I connect it to Analog input and - it shows 0

Comment: man got it! Problem was that my water was too clean  I added salt and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I had to add a salt to water to make it eletric-conductive to be able to measure a value. Long story short: my water was too clean, lol